# Short story about retired superhero woman called back to action

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, super-hero

I read this on a magazine website (or author's website) in the mid '00s. Main character was a retired and forgotten female superhero, contentedly puttering about the garden. A new villain starts tearing through the current crop of superheroes, putting them out of action one by one as the main character reluctantly goes inside, finds an old, ill-fitting uniform, and talks over the merits of getting involved with her partner. Finally, she soars into battle, and basically flicks the villain off the stage with ease. As she returns to obscurity, someone asks her name, and she responds (something like) "Just call me Undefeated."

I may be imagining some of the details (or conflating them with another story?) but the vibe was very "middle-aged women superheroes will not put up with your s***."

Comment: A. Lee Martinez possibly? It feels a bit like his type of story and [he does publish short stories on his website](https://aleemartinez.com/), though the current site only goes back to 2019.

Comment: This sounds endearingly funny. I hope it's found.

Comment: @JohnRennie Hmm, I kinda hope it's not him because if it was, it may be lost now? According to archive.org his "Short Stories" page used to be by login only, which doesn't match my memory of this.